# Getting data from a json file in Python 3.4.4

Tags: json, python-3.x

How I can get data from a json file?

Like, I have a json, with the content:

```
{Key:"MyValue",KeyTwo:{KeyThree:"Value Two"}}
```

Comment: The JSON data is not in correct format. It will cause `ValueError` with `json.loads()` and `KeyError` with `eval()`. The correct one is `{"Key":"MyValue","KeyTwo":{"KeyThree":"Value Two"}}` and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first of all, JSON strings must use double quotes. The JSON python library enforces this so you are unable to load your string. Your data needs to look like this:

```
{"Key":"MyValue","KeyTwo":{"KeyThree":"Value Two"}}
```

Then you can try this:

```
import json

data = json.load(open("file_name.json"))

for x in data:
    print("%s: %s" % (x, data[x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, modify your JSON data as follows. Let suppose it is in **Data.json**.

```
{"Key":"MyValue","KeyTwo":{"KeyThree":"Value Two"}}
```

Now, you can try the below code.

```
import json

with open('Data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().strip();

# String
print(data)
print(type(data))
"""
{"Key":"MyValue","KeyTwo":{"KeyThree":"Value Two"}}
<type 'str'>
"""

# 1st way
dict1 = eval(data) # KeyError, if your JSON data is not in correct form
print(dict1)
print(type(dict1))
"""
    {'KeyTwo': {'KeyThree': 'Value Two'}, 'Key': 'MyValue'}
    <type 'dict'>
"""

# 2nd way
dict2 = json.loads(data) # ValueError, if your JSON data is not in correct form
print(dict2)
print(type(dict2))
"""
    {u'KeyTwo': {u'KeyThree': u'Value Two'}, u'Key': u'MyValue'}
    <type 'dict'>
"""
```